# Laravel prevent direct access to ajax route

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

How do you prevent a user from directly access the route and retrieving the data.

**It is an ajax request.**

I’ve created a route

```
Route::get('/getmodels/{make_id}', ['as' => 'ajax.get.models', 'uses' => 'DashboardController@getModelsFromMake']);
```

In my kernel i’ve pointed the middleware to the named route ‘ajax.get.models’
in the routeMiddleware array.

```
'ajax.get.models' => 'App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfNotAjax’,
```

In RedirectIfNotAjax i have this. Im not sure if i’m approaching this correctly.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (!$request->ajax()) {
        return redirect()->to('/');
    }

    return $next($request);

}
```

Im not sure how do i prevent the user from accessing the url via the browser directly like **app.com/getmodels/400**

Comment: It looks good to me.  Instead of redirect you may just want to do abort(401) or something.

Comment: I know what i did that wasn't working. I didnt set the register the middleware in the rotue like. It works now.

Answer (score 0):

I change the following in the kernel

```
'ajax' => 'App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfNotAjax',
```

And i set the middleware in the route

```
Route::get('/getmodels/{make_id}', ['middleware' => 'ajax', 'as' => 'ajax.get.models', 'uses' => 'DashboardController@getModelsFromMake']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the below code, which will prevent direct access.

```
public function functionName(Request $request) {
    if(!$request->ajax()){
        abort(404);
    }
    // do something for ajax
}
```